# Demo Frame made but didnt work

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hi i made a demo java frame but after compiling it i tried running it but the frame did not open up. i did compile it n there were no errors could someone please help me with this
this is the basic code and please look into it n help me thanx alot

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class DemoFrame extends JFrame
{
        JPanel pmain,pmaster;
        JLabel lname,lclas,lyear,lroll,lemail,lphn;
        JTextField name,clas,year,roll,email,phn;
        JButton submit,reset;
        JPasswordField pass;

        void demoFrame()
        {
                setTitle("Registration Form");
                setSize(700,700);

                lname=new JLabel("Name");
                lclas=new JLabel("clas");
                lyear=new JLabel("Year");
                lemail=new JLabel("Email");
                lphn=new JLabel("Phone");
                lroll=new JLabel("Roll No.");

                name=new JTextField(10);
                clas=new JTextField(10);
                year=new JTextField(10);
                email=new JTextField(10);
                phn=new JTextField(10);
                roll=new JTextField(10);

                submit=new JButton("Register Now");
                reset=new JButton("Reset");

                pmain=new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2,3,3));
                        pmain.add(lname);
                        pmain.add(name);

                        pmain.add(lclas);
                        pmain.add(clas);

                        pmain.add(lroll);
                        pmain.add(roll);

                        pmain.add(lemail);
                        pmain.add(email);

                        pmain.add(lphn);
                        pmain.add(phn);

                pmaster=new JPanel();
                        pmaster.add(pmain);
        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                DemoFrame obj=new DemoFrame();
                obj.demoFrame();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Inside `demoFrame()` or main method call `setVisible()` to the frame:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    DemoFrame obj=new DemoFrame();
    obj.demoFrame();
    obj.setVisible(true)
}
```

Also I noticed that you didn't add `pmaster` to the frame, add this line:

```
  pmaster.add(pmain);
  add(pmaster,BorderLayout.CENTER);// PAGE_START , PAGE_END, LINE_START, LINE_END Also can be used
```

Another thing, add this line too :

```
setTitle("Registration Form");
setSize(700,700);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//<<<
```